# Cant see friends status or last onlne

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, viber-messenger

Hi i exchanged phone numbers with a friend but i cant cant see if shes online or when was last seen on viber and whatsapp.What might be the posibble reasons for that?Maybe she forgot to add my number to her phone contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They (your friend) may have set the Last Seen online feature to **No one** or to **My contacts only** (*WhatsApp : Settings  > Account > Privacy*).  If it's set to **My contacts only** you're probably not on their (her) contact list. And the same thing for Viber as well.